# Unable to read HTML data - Python

Tags: python, html, urllib2, mechanize

I am attempting to parse html data from a website using BeautifulSoup for python. However, urllib2 or mechanize is not able to read the whole html format. The returned data is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    EC 4.1.2.13 - Fructose-bisphosphate aldolase    </title>
    <meta name="description" content="Information on EC 4.1.2.13 - Fructose-bisphosphate aldolase">
    <meta name="keywords" content="EC,Number,Enzyme,Pathway,Reaction,Organism,Substrate,Cofactor,Inhibitor,Compound,KM Value,KI Value,IC50 Value,pi Value,Turnover Number,pH,Temperature,Optimum,Range,Source Tissue,BLAST,Subunits,Modification,Crystallization,Stability,Purification">
</head>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<frameset cols="190,*" border="0">
    <frame name="navigation" src="flat_navigation.php4?ecno=4.1.2.13&organism_list=Mycobacterium tuberculosis&Suchword=&UniProtAcc=P67475" frameborder="no">
    <frameset rows="110,*" border="0">
            <frame name="header" src="flat_head.php4?ecno=4.1.2.13" frameborder="no">

        <frame name="flat" src="flat_result.php4?ecno=4.1.2.13&organism_list=Mycobacterium tuberculosis&Suchword=&UniProtAcc=P67475" frameborder="no">

    </frameset>
</frameset>
<noframes>
<body>
<h1>EC 4.1.2.13 - Fructose-bisphosphate aldolase </h1>

<a href="flat_result.php4?ecno=4.1.2.13&organism_list=Mycobacterium tuberculosis&Suchword=&UniProtAcc=P67475">More detailed information on the enzyme EC 4.1.2.13 - Fructose-bisphosphate aldolase</a>

Sorry, but your browser doesn't support frames. Please use another browser!
</body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

When I manually open the webste using Internet Explorer the whole html can be read. Is there anyway using urllib2, mechanize, or BeautifulSoup to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the content is in the frames. You can either parse the page and look for the `src` attribute of the main `<frame>` element or directly request the frame. In most browsers, you can right-click and select "Frame Properties" or so to get the frame's URL.